# pytorch running: Runtime Error: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, runtime-error, google-colaboratory, torchvision

I running the python code in the Google Colab. The code is related to execution a Spiking Neural Networks.
When I plotting neuron's activations, there is a runtime error: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu!
notice: This function is derived from:
https:https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/Spiking-Neural-Network-SNN-with-PyTorch-where-Backpropagation-engenders-STDP/blob/master/Spiking%20Neural%20Networks%20with%20PyTorch.ipynb

> ## plotting neuron's activations:
>
> ```
> spiking_model.visualize_all_neurons(x)> 
> def visualize_all_neurons(self, x):
>     assert x.shape[0] == 1 and len(x.shape) == 4,("Pass only 1 example to SpikingNet.visualize(x) with outer dimension shape of 1.")
>     _, layers_state = self.forward_through_time(x)
>
>     for i, (all_layer_states, all_layer_outputs) in enumerate(layers_state):
>         layer_state  = torch.stack(all_layer_states).data.cpu().numpy().squeeze().transpose()
>         layer_output = torch.stack(all_layer_outputs).data.cpu().numpy().squeeze().transpose()
>
>         self.plot_layer(layer_state, title="Inner state values of neurons for layer {}".format(i))
>         self.plot_layer(layer_output, title="Output spikes (activation) values of neurons for layer {}".format(i))
> ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUh8P.jpg)